# Как скачать файл в несуществующую директорию с помощью wget?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Я пытаюсь скачать файл, добавить к его имени расширение `.safetensors` и переместить его в нужную папку (которой до этого может и не существовать).

Я пробовал:

```bash
wget -P /content/gdrive/cron_test/ https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888 --output-document=newfile.safetensors
wget -P /content/gdrive/cron_test/ -O newfile.safetensors  https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888
```

Ошибки нет, но файл оказывается в `/content/newfile.safetensors`, а нужно, чтобы он был в `/content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors`.

```bash
wget -P /content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888
```

В итоге получается вот так `/content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors/43888`.

```bash
wget -O /content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888
```

> /content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors: No such file or directory

```bash
mkdir  /content/gdrive/cron_test/
wget -O /content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888
```

> /content/gdrive/cron_test/: No such file or directory

Что нужно сделать, чтобы переместить файл в каталог и поменять его расширение?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать не одну, а несколько вложенных друг в друга директорий, необходимо использовать команду [`mkdir`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=mkdir&category=1&russian=0) c флагом `-p` (то же, что и флаг `-⁠-⁠parents`).

Например:

```bash
mkdir -p a/b/c
```

Теперь можно скачивать файл в эту директорию при помощи [`wget`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=wget&category=1&russian=0) с опцией `-O` (то же самое, что и опция `-⁠-⁠output-document=`):

```bash
wget <url> -O a/b/c/newfile.safetensors
```

Опция `-P` (она же `-⁠-⁠directory-prefix=`) игнорируется, если задана опция `-O`, поэтому не нужно их использовать одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось параметр программы [wget](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=wget&category=1&russian=0) `-x` не создает каталоги пользователя, а повторяет вложенность файла с сайта.
Спасибо [Vadik Sirekanyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177676/vadik-sirekanyan) за разъяснение.

---

От себя предложу вариант с `curl` хоть его и нет в метках, но рассмотреть возможность реализации с его помощью все же возможно:

Параметры запуска:

- -o, --output FILE - Write output to  instead of stdout
- --create-dirs - Create necessary local directory hierarchy

пример строки для запуска:

```
curl https://civitai.com/api/download/models/43888 -o /content/gdrive/cron_test/newfile.safetensors --create-dirs
```

Comment: Опция `-x` [создает](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=wget&category=1&russian=0) структуру папок, начиная с главной страницы сервера. Если запустить ваш код, то файл будет создан в директории `./civitai.com/api/download/models/43888`, а не `/content/gdrive/cron_test`. Проверял на GNU Wget 1.21 built on linux-gnu.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan да, действительно, в моем мануале это описано совсем не очевидно и поведение будет не таким как ожидалось, спасибо!